# WebAPI how to specify which route a controller will be reached

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have been experimenting with MVC WebAPI, pretty cool stuff. But I am struggling with the concept of routes.

as an example I have a webAPI project structure something like the following:

Project:

- Controllers

  - Customers

    - CustomerController.cs
    - CustomerAddressController.cs
  - Products

    - ProductCategoriesController.cs
    - ProductsController

Currently I have one API route defined In WebApiConfig.cs

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "CustomerApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/customer/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

This worked fine when I only had the customer related controllers.
so I could call:

- GET api/customer/CustomerAddress/?customerID= 1234

but now that I have added the Product related controllers I find with the configuration as is (of course) to get products I have to call the Uri:

- GET api/customer/products/?prodID= 5678   *BUT I don't want this Uri

instead I want:

- GET api/products/?prodID= 5678

and for product categories I would like something akin to:

- GET api/products/categories/?catID= 1357

I thought that what I had to do was add more routes, but I cant find how to associate the various controllers with the route I wish for them?

if I do add another route I end up with two different uri's routing to each of the controllers I have built.

How can I achieve the logical partitioning that I desire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Web Api 2, you can smoothly define specific routing for your actions. For example :

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/customer")]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        // ..
    }

    [Route("api/customer/{customerID}")]
    public Customer GetCustomer(int customerID)
    {
        // ..
    }

    [Route("api/customer/CustomerAddresses/{customerID}")]
    public Address GetCustomerAddresses(int customerID)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/product")]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        // ..
    }

    [Route("api/product/{prodID}")]
    public Product GetProduct(int prodID)
    {
        // ..
    }

    [Route("api/product/categories/{catID}")]
    public Category GetCategory(int catID)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect: I had been reading that WebAPI had removed method decoration, if that was true, I am happy to see it back.

Thank you for this answer.